# Unable to find suitable value for read capacity of my Dynamo DB table

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am using aws serivces. I have a Dynamo DB table which is populated using Lambda function. I created lambda function for delete rows from Dynamo DB table as well. I have used full table scan to delete a particular row.my lambda got throttled so i requested for increasing the limit and now its working fine. But now Dynamo DB getting throttled showing throttled read requests and I find some of the rows not deleted in my Dynamo DB table.I increased the read request capacity but not sure how much to increase it.I have checked the amazon docs as well they are showing you can increase it as per your requirements. Any help will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official `DynamoDB` [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html):

> One read capacity unit represents one strongly consistent read per second, or two eventually consistent reads per second, for items up to 4 KB in size.

The capacity you want to provision depends on the number of requests per second and the size of your items.